# Permission Denied when deploying docker image to Kubernetes Engine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

When I [image: deploy] a Docker image to [Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/)

I get this permission denied error [image]

I'm using [Google Container-Registry/](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/) to store docker image that was build with [cloud build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This totally looks like `backend` doesn't have 'execute' permissions in the container.

On your Dockerfile just try adding it execute permissions. Something like this:

```
RUN chmod 755 /backend
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: now I get another error :C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489347/how-to-create-a-binary-that-contains-zoneinfo-zip but is related to go binary :(